# Backbone JST Template, How to Render Rails Partials

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

A couple of select elements in my JST Template rely on the db to populate choices. Can I pull a rails partial into my template? What is the best way to do this?

For example a partial like this:

_font_faces.html.haml

```
.font_face
  = select("font", "style", Font.all.collect {|f| [ f.name, f.id ] })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question is, you don't want to put that kind of logic into your view anyways. There should be a separate backbone collection made, a font collection, not a call to the db in the view.

Answer (score 1):

If you name something like choices.jst.eco.haml the asset pipeline will compile the file going backwards from the file extension.  So, the HAML compiler will run first, then the ECO compiler, then the JST gem will throw all that compiled code into the JST object that you can reference in your view.

Comment: hey thanks for the reply. is this a common pattern of doing this? if you don't mind, you know of any tutorials or documentation? i don't want to upset the flow of the application and that sorta sounds like a hack that my team-mates might complain about. but if it's the only way, i would definitely consider doing it. thanks!

Comment: @botbot It's a common solution if you need to run Ruby code in your JavaScript template. But I also agree that, in general, data should be passed to the view/template rather than trying to access it directly.